# NSTimer is not correct on OS X(OS X 10.9)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I use the code below to trigger and execute some function every 1 second

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:nil]`

but I found that the timer is not correct.

It is always 2 times faster than normal.

Your comment welcome

Comment: I don't think that NSTimer is wrong, it would have been spotted already by Apple. You need to give more details especially how you measure and what else your system does.

Comment: I'm not good in OS X but in iOS I often add `NSTimer` object into a `NSRunloop` object. Then it runs well

Comment: What are the bets that you scheduled two timers? The working approach to finding bugs: Tell yourself that _you_ did something wrong, and then all you need is find _what_ you did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimer is most likely not wrong. Apple would have spotted it. You didn't provide any code, but I would surmise that you are allowing two timers to run because you are not invalidating them.... causing events to be triggered twice as often. I would read through your code and make sure this isn't happening.

Comment: This seems more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Would have made it a comment but I don't have 50 rep. Besides this is the best answer I could give without more info.

Comment: Perfect answer to the question based on the information given. The missing info is that the questioner added two timers, which we can't expect because then there is no question left.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `NSTimer` many times. Never had an issue like that before. You must have the timer run in multiple threads. Please confirm.

```
-(void)callIt:(NSTimer *)timer{
   NSLog(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(callIt:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
```

Besides, I don't think that the [osx](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) has api like `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target:selector:`